# fatal error multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c++

I got this error but I don't understand it because "int const ITEMS" was never declared in DisplayErrorMessage.cpp like what it said in the error below..Any help.

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "int const ITEMS" (?ITEMS@@3HB) already defined in DisplayErrorMessage.obj
1>MakeSelection.obj : error LNK2005: "int const ITEMS" (?ITEMS@@3HB) already defined in DisplayErrorMessage.obj
1>ShowMenu.obj : error LNK2005: "int const ITEMS" (?ITEMS@@3HB) already defined in DisplayErrorMessage.obj
1>c:\users\kanaan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Assign2\Debug\Assign2.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Here is the code:

Header file

```
#ifndef _VENDINGMACHINE_H_
#define _VENDINGMACHINE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

  //extern int Denominations;
  extern int const ITEMS = 9;

  extern int Coins[5];
  extern int NumCoins[5]; //assume we have 10 coins of each denomination

   extern int ItemPrice[ITEMS ]; //price in cents
   extern int NumItems[ITEMS]; 


//extern double Total_Price;
//extern double Item_Total;

class VendingMachine{
public:
    void MakeSelection();
    int ReturnChange(int change, int Coins[], int NumCoins[]);
    void ShowMenu();
    void DisplayErrorMessage(int error);
    void PrintConfidentialInformation(int Denominations, int Items, int Coins[], 
                                                    int NumCoins[], int ItemPrice[] , int NumItems[]);

private:
    int selection;
    string code;
    double Each_Item[ITEMS];       //price for each item
};
#endif //_VENDING_MACHINE_H_
```

The cpp files are as follows.
MakeSelection.cpp
    #include "Vending Machine.h"

```
void VendingMachine::MakeSelection(){



   //assume we have 10 coins of each denomination

  double Total_Price;
// double Item_Total;

  int Coins[5] = {100, 50, 20, 10, 5};
   int NumCoins[5] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10}; 
    int ItemPrice[ITEMS] = { 75, 120, 120, 100, 150, 95, 110, 50, 120 }; //price in cents
  int NumItems[ ITEMS] = { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };

    string Product[ITEMS] = {"Water","Coke","Diet Coke","Iced Tea","Swiss Chocolate","Candy",
                                                    "Chips","Bubble Gum","Turkish Delight"};
    int b = 0;
int a = 1;

cout << "Please enter the number of your choice from the menu above. " << endl;

do{
    cout << "\nEnter the number of product OR End transaction: " << endl;
    cin >> selection;
    cout << "\nYou have selected " <<Product[selection] << endl;

    if(selection >= 1 && selection <= 9){

        NumItems[selection - 1] = NumItems[selection - 1] - 1;

        if(NumItems[selection - 1] >= 0)
            Total_Price = Total_Price + ItemPrice[selection - 1];

        else{
            int error = 1;
            DisplayErrorMessage(error);         //Item finised
            cout <<selection<< endl;
        }
    }
    else if(selection == 10)
        cout << "\nTransaction Ended" << endl;

    else if(selection == 99){

        cout << "Enter the code to access maintanance: " <<endl;
        cin >> code;

        while(code != "111"){
            int error = 2;
            DisplayErrorMessage(error);
            cin >> code;
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\tSales Report " << endl;
        cout << "==================================================== " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Number of each product sold with Income cost: " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        do{
            if(NumItems[b] >= 0){

                Each_Item[b] = Each_Item[b] + ItemPrice[b];

                cout << NumItems[b] << "" << Product[b] << " sold for the total cost of " <<(10 - NumItems [b]) * Each_Item[b]/ 100 <<endl;   

                Total_Price = Total_Price + ((10 - NumItems[b]) * Each_Item[b]/100);
            }
            b++;
        }while(a <= ITEMS);
    }
    else{ 
        int error = 3;
        DisplayErrorMessage(error);
    }
}while(selection != 10);
}
```

DisplayErrorMessage.cpp

```
#include "Vending Machine.h"

void VendingMachine::DisplayErrorMessage(int error){

if (error == 1){
    cout << "\nSorry we are run out of item number ";
}
else if (error == 2){
    cout << "\nInvalid selection - Please re-select your choice" << endl;
}
else if (error == 3){
    cout << "\nIncorrect Password - Please re-enter" << endl;
}
else
    cout << "\nNot enough fund" << endl;
}
```

Help pliz.

Comment: I bet you declared it (and accidentally defined it) in some header file.

Comment: include guards may help you

Comment: May be just an include that doesn't use `pragma one` ...

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: Not in the current case, that's a link error, not a compilation error.

Comment: @Trinimon, `pragma once`, but it's not 100% portable because it's not a part of c++ standart, however I don't know any modern compiler that can't handle it

Comment: Why is your indentation all weird?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is a multiple definition problem, not a missing definition problem.

Comment: @aschepler: Ooh I never noticed that that FAQ doesn't cover multiple definitions.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: yes, that was what I was trying to type: `pragma once` of course - `c` like in chameleon, which can hide quite good :) I know this is less spread and newer than using `DEFINE`. Just wanted to give a potential root cause that can lead to duplicated definitions.

Answer (score 5):

#### Your problem

```
extern int const ITEMS = 9;
```

Marking this `extern` is correct, but then you went ahead and gave it a definition, undoing all that lovely correctness.

When you define symbols in headers, whether you're using include guards *or not*, when your translation units are linked together you will get multiple definition errors.

You must define the symbol `ITEMS` in precisely *one* translation unit — this generally means defining it in a "source" file, *not* a header.

---

#### Naive fix

So, in your header:

```
extern int const ITEMS;  // definition found elsewhere
```

And then, in *one* .cpp file:

```
int const ITEMS = 9;
```

---

#### Real fix

But, **oops!** You need this constant in your headers, because some array sizes rely on it.

So, instead of making one symbol `ITEMS` that is shared between all translation units in your program, you will have to have a definition local to *each* translation unit. To do this, we use the `static` keyword to make the symbol file-static.

So, in your header:

```
static int const ITEMS = 9;  // visible only in this TU
```

Now, multiple translation units (loosely speaking, this means each .cpp that uses this header) will have their own version of `ITEMS`, just as before... but this time, because they're marked `static`, each is *local* to that translation unit, so they will not conflict at link-time.

Answer (score 5):

First, in your header `Vending Machine.h` (by the way, it's a bad idea to have spaces in file names, why don't you just name it `VendingMachine.h`?), the following line:

```
  extern int const ITEMS = 9;
```

is a *definition*, not a declaration, despite the `extern`, because of the initializer part (the "`= 9`").

Now, this header is included by multiple source (`.cpp`) files, and `ITEMS` has *external linkage* (explicitly because of `extern`), resulting in each source file (re)defining *the same* `ITEMS`, hence the multiple definition error you get.

If you change the line to

```
  static int const ITEMS = 9;
```

or simply

```
  int const ITEMS = 9;
```

(which is actually equivalent because of the particular rules for `const` globals), then each `ITEMS` (in each source file) will have *internal linkage* and that will be all fine.

---

**Edit:** Additionally, the following answer is a nice explanation of the two meanings of `extern` ("external linkage" and "declare, not define"): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840401

**Edit:** Two other good answers about `extern` (which add the meaning of "static storage duration"): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3994572 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18450398

Answer (score 3):

```
  extern int const ITEMS = 9;
```

Since you include an initializer, this declaration is also a definition.  And since you declare it `extern`, there is only one object `ITEMS`.  But with that line in the header file, everything that includes the header makes its own definition.

You could leave off the `extern`, in which case the `const` will imply `static`.

```
  int const ITEMS = 9;
```

Then `ITEMS` is a different object in each compilation unit, but that doesn't matter much if you always use it as a value, and never do anything with its address.

Or if you have C++11 support enabled, you could have:

```
  constexpr int ITEMS = 9;
```

... which tells the compiler to treat the one `ITEMS` object similarly to an `inline` function, and it can be defined more than once.